: expected on multiple ternary `if-else` rendering of componentes in React... How do I "Finish" or "Close" the ternary statement?
I am creating a simple component which renders a colored tag on my HTML:
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import "./styles.scss";

interface ColorTagProps {
    tagType?: string;
    tagText?: string;
}

/**
 * Renderiza uma `Color Tag` de acordo com o tipo de tag recebido no Props ao gerar o componente.
 * São eles:
 *
 * - Success
 * - Warning
 * - Danger
 * - Info
 *
 * **/
export class ColorTag extends Component<ColorTagProps> {

    render() {
        return (
            this.props.tagType === "Success" ?
                (
                    <div
                        style={{
                            display: "flex",
                            alignItems: "center",
                            justifyContent: "space-between",
                        }}
                    >
                        <div className="tagType-success">{this.props.tagText}</div>
                    </div>) :
                this.props.tagType === "Warning" ?
                    (
                        <div
                            style={{
                                display: "flex",
                                alignItems: "center",
                                justifyContent: "space-between",
                            }}
                        >
                            <div className="tagType-warning">{this.props.tagText}</div>
                        </div>) :
                    this.props.tagType === "Danger" ?
                    (
                        <div
                            style={{
                                display: "flex",
                                alignItems: "center",
                                justifyContent: "space-between",
                            }}
                        >
                            <div className="tagType-danger">{this.props.tagText}</div>
                        </div>
                    )
        )
    }
}

export default ColorTag;

I expected that the code returned no errors, but it still thinking that will be other "Elses", tho the last one is the final one and I don't want to create a additional : (Else).
How do I "Finish" and "Close" the logic?

I see you're using Class Component, so you can declare in your state a new variable, in that variable the value changes depends on whatever you want, and in the render you can use a switch-case to render what component. That's cleaner than using multiple ternaries.
And another tip for you, you repeat a lot of code and style, you can create a component and pass the props to the component, you can use the switch variable and save into the variable the name of the tagType and its dynamic.

Hi @alonso ! Yes, this is actually a component, which I will call it by <ColorTag tagType={"Success"} tagText={"Active"} />... I did'nt understand what you said about creating a state with a new variable tho. The message that is returning to me is ": was expected" right after the ending of this.props.tagType === "Warning" ?...

See your component, all coding is the same, the only thing that is this part className="tagType-danger", you can use a variable and the render is dynamic like this:
className="tagType-{this.props.tagType}}", and all the block can be just one

I see! Sorry, I did not got that right away. I will try to improve this... So I could do tagType-{this.props.tagType}... I understood it now. Thanks for the tip... What about the closing of the ternary if statement? ;-;

This is my idea for your example:
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import "./styles.scss";

interface ColorTagProps {
    tagType?: string;
    tagText?: string;
}

/**
 * Renderiza uma `Color Tag` de acordo com o tipo de tag recebido no Props ao gerar o componente.
 * São eles:
 *
 * - Success
 * - Warning
 * - Danger
 * - Info
 *
 * **/
export class ColorTag extends Component<ColorTagProps> {

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                }}
            >
                <div className={`tagType-${this.props.tagType}`}>{this.props.tagText}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

I don't know if the code syntax is ok, I write all the code here

Oh, I see it now. So that eliminates the necessite to use the ternary conditions completelly! It solves the problem in a elegant way indeed, thanks friend.
